# WPF vs Windows WebBrowser Control

Tags: wpf

In Windows Form Web Browser Control,
if i have a String variable containing text, i can use memory stream to display the data via `Webbrowser.documentstream.`

However in WPF Web Browser Control, if I use the same technique via , nothing shows up. But the "view source page" contains the text.

How do i solve this?

```
        Byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(code);


        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        //webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.wpf-tutorial.com");
        webBrowser.NavigateToStream(ms);
```

code store the following string

```
@"
<div style="color:Black;background-color:White;"><pre>
<span style="color:Blue;">using</span> System;
<span style="color:Blue;">using</span> System.Collections.Generic;
<span style="color:Blue;">using</span> System.Linq;
<span style="color:Blue;">using</span> System.Text;
<span style="color:Blue;">using</span> System.Threading.Tasks;

<span style="color:Blue;">namespace</span> ColorCodeTest{    
    <span style="color:Blue;">class</span> Program
    {
        <span style="color:Blue;">static</span> <span style="color:Blue;">void</span> Main(<span style="color:Blue;">string</span>[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(<span style="color:#A31515;">&quot;&amp;lt;WTF&gt;&quot;</span>);
        }
    }
}

</pre></div>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, must be something wrong with the text itself? Try running the code though HtmlEncode before passing it in to the control:

```
code = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(code);
```

Comment: nope =/ still the same. If i were to save it as a html file, and use navigate(), it works. But i want to do it from memory stream

Comment: Again, it seems to be working fine for me. The only other thing I can see is that your code appears to have some malformed html which should instead be `Console.WriteLine(<span style="color:#A31515;">&quot;&lt;WTF&gt;&quot;</span>);`.

Comment: One last thing, by itself it's not valid html so try wrapping it in a proper page i.e. `code = "<html><head></head><body><pre>" + code + "</pre></body></html>";`

Comment: So weird. My windowstyle was None. I set it to singleborder and the html shows. Then i reverted it back to None. Now it works. Hmm